# How to control Api calls from calling multiple times using javascript in service worker for chrome extension manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, refresh-token, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my code im having a fucntion called refresh token which is been used to call at different methods / functions.If this refresh token has been called multiple times at same time it will get null response.This is the example i created from my code:
In service worker from this example code i need solution to stop refreshtoken() from calling multiple times at same time.

````
exampleApi2()
exampleApi3()
exampleApi4()

function exampleApi1() {
    //some api call with token
    if (response === 'refreshtoken expired') {
await  refreshToken()
        examplApi1()
    }
}
function exampleApi2() {
    //some api call with token
    if (response === 'refreshtoken expired') {
await  refreshToken()
        examplApi2()
    }
}
function exampleApi3() {
    //some api call with token
    if (response === 'refreshtoken expired') {
await  refreshToken()
        examplApi3()
    }
}
function exampleApi4() {
    //some api call with token
    if (response === 'refreshtoken expired') {
await  refreshToken()
        examplApi4()
    }
}

   function refreshToken() {
        //refreshtoken api call to fetch new token
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is not an out of the box working solution but rather a hint how could you tackle your issue.*

You could declare your constants:

```
const unauthorizedRoutes = [];
let interval = null;
const routes = {
  exampleApi1: "http://localhost/api1",
  exampleApi2: "http://localhost/api2",
  exampleApi3: "http://localhost/api3",
  exampleApi4: "http://localhost/api4",
};
```

Create a common method for fetch, something like that:

```
const request = async (url, method) => {
  let options = null;
  const head = new Headers();
  head.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  if (method === "GET") {
    options = {
      method: method,
      headers: head,
    };
  } else {
    options = {
      method: method,
      headers: head,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  }

  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = new Error();
    error["response"] = "refreshtoken expired";

    throw error;
  }
  const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
  if (contentType) {
    if (contentType.startsWith("application/json;")) {
      return response.json();
    } else if (contentType.startsWith("text/")) {
      return response.text();
    } else {
      return response.text();
    }
  }
};
```

Create a handler which will try to refresh token in 1s intervals (of course increase the time for your needs):

```
const handleTokenRefresh = (apiRoute) => {
  const route = unauthorizedRoutes.find((route) => route === apiRoute);
  if (!route) {
    unauthorizedRoutes.push(apiRoute);
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
  interval = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      await request("http://localhost/refreshToken", "GET");
      for (const route of unauthorizedRoutes) {
        await request(route);
      }
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
      unauthorizedRoutes = [];
    } catch (e) {}
  }, 1000);
};
```

And declare your API methods

```
const api = {
  exampleApi1: async () => {
    try {
      await request(routes.exampleApi1, "GET");
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.response === "refreshtoken expired") {
        handleTokenRefresh(routes.exampleApi1);
      }
    }
  },
  exampleApi2: async () => {
    try {
      await request(routes.exampleApi2, "GET");
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.response === "refreshtoken expired") {
        handleTokenRefresh(routes.exampleApi2);
      }
    }
  },
  exampleApi3: async () => {
    try {
      await request(routes.exampleApi3, "GET");
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.response === "refreshtoken expired") {
        handleTokenRefresh(routes.exampleApi3);
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Usage:

```js
api.exampleApi1();
api.exampleApi2();
api.exampleApi3();
```

It will try to perform a request to specified route.
If request fails, it will be pushed to array of unauthorized routes.
Your handler comes to action and tries to refresh token.
If it is successful, then it will try to perform all requests from unauthorized array.

If you want to add some logic to break from the infinite loop of refreshing the token, you can do something like that:

Declare a counter

```
let counter = 0;

const unauthorizedRoutes = [];
let interval = null;
const routes = {
  exampleApi1: "http://localhost/api1",
  exampleApi2: "http://localhost/api2",
  exampleApi3: "http://localhost/api3",
  exampleApi4: "http://localhost/api4",
};
```

Declare a method to clear the interval:

```js
const cancelInterval = () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
  unauthorizedRoutes = [];
}
```

Modify token refresh handler:

```js
const handleTokenRefresh = (apiRoute) => {
  const route = unauthorizedRoutes.find((route) => route === apiRoute);
  if (!route) {
    unauthorizedRoutes.push(apiRoute);
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
  interval = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      await request("http://localhost/refreshToken", "GET");
      for (const route of unauthorizedRoutes) {
        await request(route);
      }
      cancelInterval();
    } catch (e) {
      counter++;
      if (counter % 10 === 0) {
        cancelInterval()
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

Now, if the counter reaches 10, the whole refresh token interval will be cleared. Of course this is just a hint how you can do it.